# Jquery resizable show size while resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam building a jquery project in which people can draw on a map, they can put divs on the map that they can then move around and resize. I want a box on the side that updates the current width/height of the div while they are resizing it. At the moment it works but it only updates after they are done resizing but i want it to update live while they are resizing it.

my current code that only updates when done with resizing:

```
$(item).resizable({
            grid: Math.round(gridStand),
            stop : function(event,ui) {
                endW = Math.round($(this).outerWidth()/gridStand);
                endH = Math.round($(this).outerHeight()/gridStand);
                $(this).attr('w', endW).attr('h', endH)
                $('.standW').html('<h5>Breedte</h5><h4>'+($(item).attr('w')/2)+'</h4><span>meter</span>');
                $('.standH').html('<h5>Diepte</h5><h4>'+($(item).attr('h')/2)+'</h4><span>meter</span>')
                }
            })
            .draggable({
                grid: [ Math.round(gridStand), Math.round(gridStand) ],
                 containment: "#map", 
                 scroll: false,
                 stop : function(event,ui) {
                    endX = Math.round($(this).position().left/gridStand);
                    endY = Math.round($(this).position().top/gridStand);
                    $(this).attr('x', endX).attr('y', endY)
                }
            })
```

Does anyone know how to change this so it updates while resizing and not only when your done resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`resize`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize) event is triggered during the resize, every time the size of the resized object changes. You'll want to use that rather than `stop`, which triggers only once after the resize finishes.

Comment: thanks, it works! kinda bad cos i actualy tried resize before but i forgot to add the part where it calculates to it.